# why chrome compress my javascript file when I am debugging this file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have some uncompressed javascript files local. When I use Google Chrome browser test one file of them, it would be compressed by chrome, so I can't debug this file with Chrome developer tools, but at the same time, some other js files is normal and can be debug.

who can tell me the reason.

Comment: "it would be compressed by chrome" --- uhm, chrome doesn't compress anything

Comment: Can you give an example of the code before and after it appears to be "compressed" .. possibly its your server messing up your code somehow.

Comment: My guess is that you have unconventional line endings in your javascript file that your editor shows as newlines, but the Chrome debugger does not.  Chrome doesn't compress anything.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah,you are right,I found unconventional line endings in my js file, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting this as an answer since it ended up being the problem.  My guess is that you have unconventional line endings in your javascript file that your editor shows as newlines, but the Chrome debugger does not. Chrome doesn't compress anything.